# How can I prevent VScode launched via Anaconda from restoring previous sessions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, anaconda3

How do I remove saved session info from VScode launched via Anaconda?

I was doing a machine learning project with VScode launched via Anaconda, upon realizing my data file is too large to handle (>1GB) I decided to remove the file from file directory while having VScode opened. This caused my VScode to grind to a halt and every time I tried to restart VScode from Anaconda it resumes my previous session which leads to processing many changes and eventually raises out of memory error. I have tried to reinstall both VScode and Anaconda with no success and even though I have change the settings restore windows in the non Anaconda VScode to "None". When launching VScode with Anaconda it still attempts to restore my previous session.

Answer (score 0):

It's happened to me too, add this line to `settings.json` may fix your problem:

```json
  "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
```

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately it did not make any difference.